# RoR app - 'gem install mysql' error when running 'cap production deploy:initial'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx, deployment

I'm attempting to deploy my Ruby on Rails app to a DigitalOcean droplet and I've been using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) on how to do so, I followed a guide previously on how to deploy (a youtube video tutorial) but it didn't work so I've attempted this written guide. Everything has been working so far except when I attempt to deploy using `cap production deploy:initial` I get the following:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Along with three other errors; see screenshot.

[image]

How do I make sure it succeeds before bundling during the deploy? Is there any files I need to look at to make sure I've done everything correctly? Let me know if I need to include any other files.

Comment: Have you already installed `mysql` on the remote server?

Comment: Yep It's all installed - `mysql -u root -p' works`, and `mysql -u deploy -p` as well.

Comment: Do I need to have the exact same version of `mysql` installed on my server and using the Ruby Gem in my app's `gemfile`? If so, do you know how would I go about checking this?

Comment: ok, have you tried to install a mysql gem as  noticed in your error message?

Comment: Do you mean try install it directly on the server? If so, no I haven't :P I was expecting Bundler to do all that :P

Comment: Yep, I mean install this gem directly on the server, it should raise an error while installation and you will see the main reason of this issue.

Comment: Thanks - I've just done this and the error states `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`. It then said `mysql client is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.` I tried the `apit-get` but that didn't work and says to check the `mkmf.log` file for more details but I don't really know what I'm looking for, any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the full error message when you run `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`? Is the server `Ubuntu` or `CentOS`?

Comment: I'm getting somewhere! Thanks for your help so far :-) I've installed the MySQL gem now but I've got a really odd error, it says: `Cannot load 'Rails.application.database_configuration':
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]`. I definitely have the `database.yml` file but maybe I've set it up incorrectly (If I need to set it up, it didn't tell me how to change this in the guide I was reading).

Comment: I did rename the `database.yml` file once when I was following a different tutorial, I changed it to `database.yml.example` I think as the tutorial suggested... will that have messed up anything?

Comment: Check this gem https://github.com/rjocoleman/capistrano-upload-config

Comment: Still no luck :/ I'm not totally sure how to use that gem exactly but I had a go and nothing has changed, it still can't find the file. I'll paste in a few lines of the errors (the last line is one of many)

Comment: SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 139.59.167.166: Exception while executing on host 139.59.167.166: rake exit status: 1

rake stdout: rake aborted!

Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:

Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]

/home/deploy/apps/benchmark-your-bet/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration'

Comment: Okay I had `config/database.yml` and `config/secrets.yml` in my .gitignore for some reason - probably from the previous tutorial... I've removed that and I've gotten a step further, now I have an issue with the secret key: `Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

  config.secret_key = "long_string_here"`

Comment: just add a secret key to the devise initializer `config/initializers/devise.rb`